# Create IIS Application from Code

Tags: c#, iis

I'm working on a web service installation.
One of the things I need to do is creating a new virtual directory under the default web site.
The problem is I need to set a different application pool for that virtual directory (please don't ask why...these are the requirements and nothing I can do about it).

In IIS6, since there is no difference between virtual directories and applications I have no problem doing so.
In IIS7, it is not possible setting an application pool to a virtual directory so I need to create a new "application" and attach an application pool to it.

I couldn't find any reasonable example/tutorial for doing so in C#. I need some help please :-)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer somewhere out there.
I'm using the same code for creating the virtual directory in IIS6 and the application on IIS7:

```
  DirectoryEntry defaultWebSite = GetWebSiteEntry(DEFAULT_WEB_SITE_NAME);
  DirectoryEntry defaultWebSiteRoot = new DirectoryEntry(defaultWebSite.Path + "/Root");

  //Create and setup new virtual directory
  DirectoryEntry virtualDirectory = defaultWebSiteRoot.Children.Add(applicationName, "IIsWebVirtualDir");

  virtualDirectory.Properties["Path"][0] = physicalPath;
  virtualDirectory.Properties["AppFriendlyName"][0] = applicationName;
  virtualDirectory.CommitChanges();

  // IIS6 - it will create a virtual directory
  // IIS7 - it will create an application
  virtualDirectory.Invoke("AppCreate", 1);

  object[] param = { 0, applicationPoolName, true };
  virtualDirectory.Invoke("AppCreate3", param);
```

Comment: I'm having trouble finding `GetWebSiteEntry`. I have referenced System.Web in my class library, but can't find any sign of that method. Can you point me at some "using" or references I might need?

Answer (score 0):

With C# you can try running some server side script that creates virtual directory.

Take a script similar to:
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5adfcce1-030d-45b8-997c-bdbfa08ea459.mspx?mfr=true

And run it with 'Execute' command:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Execute_Command_in_CSharp.aspx

Comment: Mantas: Thank's for replying, I'm already familiar with these scripts (the IIS7 has the appcmd) but I need to write a c# code and besides, event using these scripts I still don't know how to create an application (virtual directory is OK).